# Adding lubridate dates to vector changes timezone and thus date

Tags: r, date, lubridate

In the R package lubridate, I can easily create a date with the following syntax:

```
> mdy("5/4/2015")
```

As expected, it produces the following result:

```
[1] "2015-05-04 UTC"
```

However, if I try to add that very value to an array, it seems to change from UTC to my local time (EDT):

```
> c(mdy("5/4/2015"))
[1] "2015-05-03 20:00:00 EDT"
```

Since I don't care about times this wouldn't affect me much except that this results in the date shifting back by 1, as follows:

```
> day(mdy("5/4/2015"))
[1] 4
> day(c(mdy("5/4/2015")))
[1] 3
```

To me, the act of adding something to an array should not change the value of that something. Am I missing something here, and is there a way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Try `Sys.setenv(TZ="UTC")`

Comment: Thanks; that appears to fix the symptom, which I appreciate, but I'm still uncomfortable with the idea that the value I put in a vector might not be the value I pull back out from the vector. I'm not sure if there's something fundamental I'm misunderstanding about how R works or if this is some quirk in lubridate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `lubridate::mdy` assumes `UTC`. When you wrap it around `c()`, it reverts back to your local timezone `EDT` because `c()` does not pass on the `timezone` attribute:

```
> attr(mdy("5/4/2015", tz = "EDT"), "tzone")
# [1] "EDT"
> attr(c(mdy("5/4/2015", tz = "EDT")), "tzone")
# NULL
```

You can do:

```
Sys.setenv(TZ = "UTC")
```

To set your local timezone to `UTC`.

Alternatively, you can specity the timezone explicitly in `mdy()`:

```
mdy("5/4/2015", tz = "UTC")
```

Comment: I guess I'm still confused as to how this can matter. From my perspective, if I put a value in an array and immediately ask the array for that value, they better be the same. Is this type of thing common in R?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from Steven's solution, you could also store your dates in a list

```
list(mdy("5/4/2015"))[[1]]
#[1] "2015-05-04 UTC"
```

This won't remove the timezone and you don't have to mess around with environment variables.
I agree with you: If you look at `c` as some form of constructor for a "vector" and you come from a `C++` or similar background, the removal of attributes (except for names) certainly seems strange.